# Tortoise SVN: How to export & import a repo

Tags: svn, import, export, tortoisesvn

this is the first time I use Tortoise svn. I actually, couldn't completely understand the sense behind the snv.

I tried  check out of full repository from an svn server, but it couldn't be comleted without errors. I think it's because of slow local network we use. It last very long... So I want to copy "the repo" into a USB disk and paste that repo into my computer. I asked IT if this is possible, and I was answered that no! I a little bit googled and found something like "export svn".

My main question is that: **Is it possible to export a repo from server, and import into my computer without need of using network.**

My second question is that: If it is possible, how? I don't want full details, I need only some keywords.

Comment: Start with reading the documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.html & https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My main question is that: Is it possible to export a repo from server, and import into my computer without need of using network.

Short answer: yes, if you have physical access to the server. Then you can export the repository to a USB drive without any network access. But normally, this wont be the case.

`svn export` basically just download the files from the server. In difference to `svn checkout` it does not create a working copy.

Comment: What is the difference between "creating a working copy" and "just downloading the files". Does "just downloading the files" instead of "creating a working copy", cause future problems for example when I want to commit changes I made.

Comment: A working copy is a construct needed by SVN allowing your normal tools (e.g. Notepad) to work with the versioned data. An export just downloads a some revision of your versioned data. So, yes you need a working copy to have the version control features. Like already pointed out, you should take a look at the SVN [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html) for a better understanding